# How do I make the fontsize smaller on points in a Python scatterplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting syntax error messages saying my arguments aren't in the right order when they are, and also I'll do `fontsize = 9` and it will say the equal sign shouldn't be there. If I do `*fontsize = 9`, the asterisk will be wrong. Does anyone know why this happens?

I went on the matplotlib website and used the annotate functions on there, and for some reason I keep running errors.

My code is really incoherent so no.

Comment: If your code is incoherent, at least break it down to a minimal example that illustrates your error or something. How are we supposed to figure out?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. I believe what you're asking is how to make the points on the scatterplot smaller - to do that, include "s = (number you choose)" in your plt.plot() statement. Experiment with values for s until you get one you like. Without the code, I have no idea why it's telling you your arguments aren't in the right order. Look at the error trace and look at the line it's complaining about and the one above it, and at least give us *those two* lines, formatted as code.

Comment: y'all i figured it out i think. You have to use fontdict in order for it to work. Or you can just color the point on the graph and then put the text in the legend using plt.legend().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try placing `fontsize=_` after your color aggument or `x,y` etc
 not at last like labels